# Как дождаться окончания ввода данных в EditText из внешнего сканера

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

К мобильному устройству подключен внешний сканер для сканирования штрих-кодов EAN13, DataMatrix (честный знак), PDF417(РАР)
Имеется фрагмент. на тем EditText. в который и происходит сканирование.
Факт окончания сканирования определяю через метод setOnKeyListener по получению CHR кодов Enter и TAB который передает внешний сканер

```
       mBinding.id05Ean.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
            override fun onKey(v: View?, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
                if ((event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) and
                    ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB) or (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                ) {
                    var qqq = mBinding.id05Ean.text.toString()
                    Log.d("vva", "$qqq")
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```

В результате работы в строке var qqq = mBinding.id05Ean.text.toString() часто получаю не полное (обрезанное) значение, хотя на экране вижу верное значение.
В методе onTextChanged тоже имею полное значение

> override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int,
> count: Int) {
> Log.d("vva", "onTextChanged: $s, $start, $before, $count")
> }

В логах событие setOnKeyListener происходит раньше чем onTextChanged
Как дождаться окончания заполнения EditText?

Comment: Я бы попробовал в OnKeyListener  просто ставить флаг что закончено, а в onTextChanged уже реагировать на изменения, если стоит флаг, поставленный в OnKeyListener

Comment: Не помогает. После того как сканер передал Enter мы ставим флаг. Но поскольку не читаемый символ то onTextChanged не вызывается.
Пробовал сохранять значение из onTextChanged и в setOnKeyListener его использовать.
Все равно как то все не стабильно.

Других объектов для ввода текста не существует?